# How to define a function in dplyr?

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I created a simple pivot table in the `dplyr` package in R. Here is my working example:

```
library(dplyr)
mean_mpg <- mean(mtcars$mpg)

# creating a new variable that shows that Miles/(US) gallon is greater than the mean or not

mtcars <-
mtcars %>%
  mutate(mpg_cat = ifelse(mpg > mean_mpg, 1,0))

mtcars %>%
  group_by(as.factor(cyl)) %>%
  summarise(sum=sum(mpg_cat),total=n()) %>%
  mutate(percentage=sum*100/total)
```

Now, I want to write a function to reuse this code:

```
get_pivot <- function(data, predictor,target) {
  result <-
    data %>%
    group_by(as.factor(predictor)) %>%
    summarise(sum=sum(target),total=n()) %>%
    mutate(percentage=sum*100/total);

  print(result)
}
```

but I receive the following error:

> Error in is.factor(x) : object 'cyl' not found

I also tried

```
get_pivot(mtcars, "cyl", "mpg_cat" )
```

but it did not work.

What should I do?

Comment: dplyr uses quotation in its functions. either implement quoting or do it the normal way without quoting. https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#quoting

Comment: Per qwr's comment, this works for me: get_pivot(mtcars, mtcars$cyl, mtcars$mpg_cat )

Comment: 'dplyr 0.8.1` imports rlang (>= 0.3.4), but the functionality in my answer requires rlang >=0.4.0. Not sure the relevance of the dplyr version in the title.  https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/v0.8.1/DESCRIPTION

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have the most recent `rlang` library update v0.4.0 (June 2019), you can use double curly brackets `{{ }}` (aka "curly curly") to make programming with dplyr easier.

```
# Note: needs installation of rlang 0.4.0 or later
get_pivot <- function(data, predictor,target) {
  result <-
    data %>%
    group_by(as.factor( {{ predictor }} )) %>%
    summarise(sum=sum( {{ target }} ),total=n()) %>%
    mutate(percentage=sum*100/total);

  print(result)
}

# Edit -- thank you Rui Barradas
> get_pivot(mtcars, cyl, mpg_cat)
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  `as.factor(cyl)`   sum total percentage
  <fct>            <dbl> <int>      <dbl>
1 4                   11    11      100  
2 6                    3     7       42.9
3 8                    0    14        0
```

The reason this is required is that `dplyr` and other `tidyverse` packages use "non-standard evaluation" like you encounter with some base R functions, like `lm(mpg~factor(am),data=mtcars)`. This practice often makes "interactive" code shorter, simpler, and easier to read, but at the cost of making programming more complicated. In this case, the `{{ }}` operator serves to transport the column you specify into the context of the function.

https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2019/06/rlang-0-4-0/

Comment: I don't know for sure but I think the non-standard evaluation actually comes from R's formula and not lm.

Comment: Also you can pass in data columns directly like `get_pivot(mtcars, mtcars$cyl, mtcars$mpg_cat)`

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. I keep meaning to sit down and take the time to properly understand `dplyr`'s non-standad eval, now I'm glad I waited until they brought in the new syntax.

Comment: The function doesn't produce the same results as the non-function version. This is because you are summing `target` not `mpg_cat` (or `target_cat`).